# Latex: Empty page between landscape and portrait page. Why?

Tags: pdfpages

I call this landscape pages from here (**main file**):

```
\begin{landscape}  
\vspace{5cm}
\chapter{XXXXX} 
\label{ch:YYYY}     
\end{landscape}
\input{./XXX/Model.tex}
```

**Model.tex:**

```
\begin{landscape}  % Querformat
\begin{flushleft} % Linksbündig
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\newpage
\noindent 
\begin{tikzpicture}

% Überschrift:
\begin{scope}[x=23.02cm,y=16.02cm]
\node[above right] at (0,1) {
\begin{large}
\noindent
\end{large}}; 
\end{scope}

% Hintergrundbild:
\useasboundingbox(0,0)rectangle(\linewidth,\textheight);
\node[anchor=south west] (Bild) at (0cm,0.139cm)
{\includegraphics[width=23cm,height=15.722cm]{1.png}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{flushleft}
\end{landscape}




    \begin{landscape}  % Querformat
    \begin{flushleft} % Linksbündig
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \newpage
    \noindent 
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    % Überschrift:
    \begin{scope}[x=23.02cm,y=16.02cm]
    \node[above right] at (0,1) {
    \begin{large}
    \noindent

    \end{large}}; 
    \end{scope}


    \useasboundingbox(0,0)rectangle(\linewidth,\textheight);
    \node[anchor=south west] (Bild) at (0cm,0.139cm)
    {\includegraphics[width=23cm,height=15.722cm]{2.png}};

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{flushleft}
    \end{landscape}
```

**main file:**

```
\section{xxx}   
\includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{3.png}
```

Comment: it's impossible to guess from your fragments why anything happens, the markup seems very strange though, `landscape` is designed to allow page breaking in a landscape section of the document, you have a series of consecutive `landscape` environments each containing a minipage so all page breaking is suppressed except the forced page break as enter and leave `landscape`. `\chapter` may or may not force a blank page depending on class options you haven;t shown. It isn't at all clear how your "main file" with `\section` relates to the rest. Try to make a complete document to shows the problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Is the whole document in landscape orientation? Or only some packages? If you like to have only sequence of pages in landscape it suffice that `\begin{landscape}` is on the begin of sequence and `\end{landscape}` on the end of sequence.

Comment: its a combination.

Comment: First, there is an automatic \clearpage every time one switches between landscape and portrait.  Second, putting \newpage inside a minipage at best does nothing.

Comment: what is the intention of `\begin{large}    \noindent    \end{large}` ? (whatever the intention that can not be the correct markup)